# Wake up application even it is not running in background

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

It should not be the first question about this subject, but after reading lots of articles and documents, i still doubt about the feasibility.

According to Apple's [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW14).

> **State Preservation and Restoration** 
> Because state preservation and
>   restoration is built in to Core Bluetooth, your app can opt in to this
>   feature to ask the system to preserve the state of your app’s central
>   and peripheral managers and to continue performing certain
>   Bluetooth-related tasks on their behalf, even when your app is no
>   longer running. When one of these tasks completes, the system
>   relaunches your app into the background and gives your app the
>   opportunity to restore its state and to handle the event
>   appropriately. In the case of the home security app described above,
>   the system would monitor the connection request, and re-relaunch the
>   app to handle the centralManager:didConnectPeripheral: delegate
>   callback when the user returned home and the connection request
>   completed.

Does it mean that we can wake up the application even if it is not running in background? and by which BT event, and implementation of code, we can wake up our application and make it run in background?